# Chrome, Slack and Thunderbird crashing on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird, slack

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem I've been having for some time on my Windows 10 laptop, whereby at some point (no specific interval but often days after startup) tabs in Chrome will start crashing, and often failing to reload or showing an out of memory. Once this starts happening, there seems no way to resolve it without a full reboot of the machine.

The peculiarity with this is that this state which the machine gets itself into also affects Thunderbird and the Slack desktop app at the same time. Most other applications continue unaffected. So I'm interesting in knowing what these three applications have in common, hoping that that will help me diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: I wonder if you have some sort of resource leak, are you running out of ephemeral ports when it happens? Anything in the Windows Event log, e.g. `Event ID 4231: A request to allocate an ephemeral port number from the global TCP port space has failed due to all such ports being in use.` Otherwise, register Procdump as the postmortem debugger by running: `mkdir C:\dumps` download procdump.exe to that location and run `procdump -ma -i`.  Next time a process crashes, does it create a dump file?

Comment: Nothing in the Windows Event log like the message above (in fact nothing that helpful, unless virtual memory errors might be the issue, which I doubt). I'll give Procdump a go. Thanks.

Comment: Use Task Manager or Performance Monitor to see if any resources are being eaten up. Also check if your disk is not almost full.

Answer (score 0):

Also, run a memory tester on your hardware